# Separate alphabetic characters from a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a javascript project and got an issue. 
I have values like this: `1231+, 83749M, 123199B`
I can get the numeric values/number only by doing this:

```
var theNumber = parseInt(1231+);
```

But how can I get the trailing characters like: `+, M, B`? I can't use substring because there can be more than one character. But characters will be always at the trail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var orig = "1231+";
var theNumber = parseInt(orig);
var theChar = orig.replace(theNumber, "");
```

Replacing "1231" in "1231+" with "" leaves "+".

Comment: You are welcome. (I love regex myself, but it is overkill for something like this.)

Answer (score 1):

use regular expressions:

Expression for you is : `[\d]`

Get all non numeric characters.

**Code example**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = '1234+';
    alert(elem.replace(/\d/g, ''));
});

//Result +
```

Comment: It's worth explaining *how* the user can use regular expressions. Give a code example of how this could be put into practice.

Comment: The only issue with this is that there could be a character in the middle of the string too - which it appears that the OP might not want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an regular expression.
Somhow like this:

```
var string = "1234+";
var regexp = /([0-9]+)(.*)/;
var result = regexp.exec(string);
```

The result will be:

```
[ '1231+',
  '1231',
  '+',
  index: 0,
  input: '1231+' ]
```

So `result[1]` will then be your number and `result[2]` your suffix.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're concerned about is **trailing characters** and not worried if there are alphabetic characters in the middle of the string then you could use this regex -

```
[^\d]*$
```

A handy tool for regex testing is http://regexpal.com/

Given that we have a pattern, we can now match that -

```
var foo = '1231+';
var trailers = foo.match(/[^\d]*$/);
console.log(trailers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var n1 = "234234M",
    n2 = "6546D",
    n3 = "4455+";
alert(n1.replace(parseInt(n1), ""));
alert(n2.replace(parseInt(n2), ""));
alert(n3.replace(parseInt(n3), ""));
```